# Is findOne(id) faster than findOne({ id }) in TypeORM with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, repository-pattern, typeorm

I'm using NestJS framework with TypeORM and PostgreSQL. Let's say I have a simple `User` entity which has only two properties: `id` and `name`

```
@Entity()
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar'
  })
  name: string;
```

Questions:

1. Is `usersRepository.findOne(id)` faster than `usersRepository.findOne({ id })`?
2. I assume that `usersRepository.findOne(id)` will be faster than `usersRepository.findOne({ name })` since `name` is not in index, won't it?

Comment: Have you benchmarked the queries? What SQL gets created for each of them?

Answer (score 8):

I created a table with 500 000 items and benchmarked some methods (the methods have been called 100 000 times):

| Method | Avg time [µs] |
| --- | --- |
| `this.usersRepository.query('SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE id = 258')` | 163.98 |
| `this.usersRepository.query('SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE name = "John"')` | 143.77 |
| `this.usersRepository.findByIds([258])` | 343.99 |
| `this.usersRepository.findOne(258)` | 326.64 |
| `this.usersRepository.findOne({ id: 258 })` | 338.89 |
| `this.usersRepository.findOne({ name: "John" })` | 298.40 |

Then it looks like `findOne(id)` isn't (much) faster than `findOne({ id })`. Moreover, `findOne({ name })` has similar results. However, it looks like using custom queries is the best option.

Comment: custom queries will always be faster option since `find` does many things (converts results into class instance object, calls listeners, etc. etc.). Also raw query by id should be faster since id is primary, so I guess you need to do better benchmarks (do warmup, do multiple tries and get average results).